# Rails: a method in a controller to count clicks without leaving

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I'm trying to make a method for a "Read more" link in my controller which will only count the click, i.e., do nothing except that. I'm using the [impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) gem to count the impressions which is all fine and dandy, but I want to count the clicks on my "Read more" links, and since the "Read more" links are only jQuery reveals there's no other controller method for them.

This is what I've got so far, I just need to send the click result without leaving or reloading the page.

```
def read_more(a)
  @article = Article(a)
  impressionist(a)
end
```

I get this error when I click the link:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Doc with id=19)
```

When it should be looking for `Article` with an ID of 19.

Any thoughts would be a huge help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer, should anyone else come into a similar issue.

```
def read_more
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  impressionist(@article)
  render :json => "Read."
end
```

Apparently you can't have arguments in controller methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can render some arbitrary text via:

```
render(:text => @document.number_of_impressions) and return
```

But I would probably just wrap that in some JSON and return that:

```
data = {:impressions => 74}
render(:json => data) and return
```

By using JSON you have the option of returning more data later, if you need too.

Comment: I don't want to render the result at this point, just submit the click to the database. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
@document.increment!(:number_of_impressions)
```

to your controller.

If you don't want to save the document as you increment the value just remove the bang on `increment`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
render :nothing => true
```